# How to create a mediawiki page by using queries?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I am trying to add pages to my mediawiki but I have really big data so I have to do it automatically. I have been trying to write some queries but anyone is working. Which tables do I have to update to create a page ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using queries try using MediaWiki's [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page)